# How do I slim down this vb.net code for creating files

Tags: vb.net

```
Sub file_createAA()
 Dim filepath As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments, "calculator\addition\attack\1.txt")
 If Not System.IO.File.Exists(filepath) Then
    System.IO.File.Create(filepath).Dispose()
 End If
End Sub
```

This code is repeated 64 times, each time creating a new file. The code below, also repeated 64 times with each slightly varied, also makes the folder paths required. Is there any way to slim this down as each one is rather long.

```
My.Computer.FileSystem.CreateDirectory(System.IO.Path.Combine(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments, "calculator\addition\attack"))
```

Comment: What are the differences among the 64 times? If it's only a different file path, then make the file path a parameter to the `Sub`.

Comment: It creates a text file 1-4.txt in each folder, addition, subtraction, multiplication and division, which are in a folder either time attack or elimination.

Comment: You can import the namespaces so you would be able to use the methods directly.

Comment: There is probably a better way to accomplish your goal than to create all of the text records...a database perhaps... Maybe you could post some more about what you want to accomplish and things you have tried that did not work.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
Sub file_createAA(dir1 As String, dir2 As String)

    '' dir1 can be one of these: addition, subtraction, multiplication, division
    '' dir2 can be on of these: attack, elimination
    Dim index As Integer = 1
    Dim filepath As String = System.IO.Path.Combine(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.MyDocuments, String.Format("calculator\{0}\{1}\", dir1, dir2))

    Try
        Do Until index = 5
            If Not System.IO.File.Exists(filepath & index & ".txt") Then
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(filepath)
                System.IO.File.Create(filepath & index & ".txt").Dispose()
            End If
            index += 1
        Loop
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

When you call your sub, you would do something like this:

```
file_createAA("addition", "attack")
file_createAA("subtraction", "attack")
file_createAA("multiplication", "attack")
file_createAA("division", "attack")
file_createAA("addition", "elimination")
file_createAA("subtraction", "elimination")
file_createAA("multiplication", "elimination")
file_createAA("division", "elimination")
```

This then actually means that if you ever wanted to just create 1 file instead of them all, you could call the sub once with the relevant parameters. I think this is what you were asking for :P Oh and also, it now creates the directories, sub directories and files if they don't exist. If this isn't what you wanted just ask and I'll be happy to help. :)